# Oaxaca Decomposition

Tags: r, economics

I'm trying to do a Oaxaca regression using IPUMS CPS data but I keep getting errors. I was wondering, if anyone here is able to help me with this issue.

**CODE:**

```
library("oaxaca")

oaxaca1<-oaxaca(HOURWAGE ~ age + male + educ_hs + educ_smcoll + educ_bach + educ_adv |white| educ_hs + educ_smcoll + educ_bach + educ_adv, data = data1, R = 1000)
```

**CONSOLE:**

> Variables d1 + d2 + d3 + ... in argument 'formula' must indicate membership in mutually exclusive categories.

What should I do to fix this?

PS: Education, "white" and "male" are dummy variables. My data has "1130166" observations.